# SQL grouping/aggregate per given list

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you perform the SQL query to group rows based on a given value for a specific column. For example lets say we have a table1

| id | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 20 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 5 |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |

and would like to have a query given another table2 with values

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 7 |

and I would like to have a results table grouping the rows up to the given id.  So something like

| id | total quantity | total cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 3 | 23 | 45 |
| 7 | 51 | 104 |

Not really sure if I should call it grouping, its more of a join/aggregate results from the beginning to that specific row/id.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Join by `t1.id <= t2.id` then aggregate. Joining condition does not have to be `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
         SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) total_quantity,
         SUM(quantity * price) OVER (ORDER BY id) total_cost
  FROM table1
) t  
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

For prior versions you can do it with a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT t2.id, 
       SUM(t1.quantity) total_quantity, 
       SUM(t1.quantity * t1.price) total_cost
FROM table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id <= t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id
ORDER BY t2.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=501df8a7c52a0bcb479d0f08d8fab729).

Answer (score -1):

There is some information in your tables definition that might be ambiguous, so let me make a couple of assumptions:

I am going to assume that the `id` field on both table1 and table2 has different meaning. What i mean by that is that id 1 on table 1 might refer to the id of an order, while id1 on tabled might refer to a customer, client, or vendor.

I will rename the `id` field on `table1` to `"order_id"`, as this looks like a table that contains order made, maybe by customers. At the same time, i will add a field `customer_id`. This field corresponds to the `id` field in table2, which we will also rename.

So table1 ends up being:

order_id | quantity |  price | customer_id
1  |    10    |    1.5   | 7
2  |    5     |    2     | 3
3  |    8     |    2.5   | 1
4  |    20    |    1     | 1
5  |    3     |    4     | 3
6  |    4     |    5     | 3
7  |    1     |    7     | 7

and table2 is:

customer_id
1
3
7

Now we can tie both tables by customer id and do:

```
select customer_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity, sum(price) as total_price from table1 left join table2 on table1.customer_id=table2.customer_id group by customer_id.
```

please let me know if i misinterpreted your intention.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I guess using an id can be confusing.  But its not really order id nor customer id, it should really be a time.  And the results is more of a summary at that time, of how much was sold.  In short, for my example, the id in table1 is the same/related to id in table2

Comment: So the ids are not ids, are actually timestamps? and they have the same meaning? in that case, you do not need a second table. you can just do "select id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity, sum(price) as total_price from table1 group by id". It is important to give the scenario data of a question in an accurate way.